# ffmpeg error when transmuxing from mkv to mp4

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a problem with the output file  generated from this command:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mkv -ss 00:20:00 -to 00:22:00 -c copy out.mp4
```

When I ffprobe the out.mp4, I have this error:

```
"Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none, 1280x692, 2598 kb/s): unspecified pixel format".
```

The in.mkv file with ffprobe present this:

```
`"streams":
        {
            "index": 0,
            "codec_name": "h264",
            "codec_long_name": "H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10",
            "profile": "High",
            "codec_type": "video",
            "codec_time_base": "1001/48000",
            "codec_tag_string": "[0][0][0][0]",
            "codec_tag": "0x0000",
            "width": 1280,
            "height": 692,
            "coded_width": 1280,
            "coded_height": 704,
            "has_b_frames": 2,
            "sample_aspect_ratio": "1:1",
            "display_aspect_ratio": "320:173",
            "pix_fmt": "yuv420p"}
```

Comment: Is it working without the `-ss 00:20:00 -to 00:22:00`? Are there any other streams in `in.mkv`, like audio stream? What is the version of FFmpeg?

Comment: You are trying to cut the video. This means you will have to re-encode.

Comment: yes without '-ss 00:20:00 -to 00:22:00' is working. There is 1 audio track and if i cut in.mkv  with this command  'ffmpeg -i in.mkv -ss 00:20:00 -to 00:22:00 -c:v copy -an out.mp4' ffprobe show pixfmt

Comment: but i don't understand the reason of this.

Answer (score 0):

When the cut is done it should have at least one I-frame to play that part of video and FFmpeg is looking for the nearest I-frame to the specified cut time if you use `-ss` option **before** specifying the source with `-i` option:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:20:00 -i in.mkv -to 00:22:00 -c copy out.mp4
```

If you specify `-ss` option **after** the source (like in your example) FFmpeg is looking for that I-frame in the output data to do the cut and it can happen that in the time you specified there are no I-frames so the input needs to be re-encoded to create one (so you can not use `-c copy`).

You can check where are the I-frames in your video file by using this `ffprobe` command:

```
ffprobe -loglevel error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries packet=pts_time,flags -of csv=print_section=0 -sexagesimal in.mkv | findstr K > in.txt
```

This command will create `in.txt` file with the list of times for frames flagged as `K` (keyframes).

Comment: Lex thank for answer but i must ask you there is a ffprobe command to view what kind of frames i have in the time i specifed

Comment: @Riccardocernusco I've edited my answer and added the solution how to find out where are the keyframes in your video file.

Comment: i did your command and there are I-frames in that range. If can be useful this is the warning by ffmpeg         'Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none, 1200x720, 2680 kb/s): unspecified pixel format'. The in.mkv there is this info: Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1200x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 5:3], q=2-31, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 16k tbn, 1k tbc (default)

Comment: @Riccardocernusco I've already answered that problem in your separate post: https://superuser.com/a/1702239/167207