# Experiencing an “unspecified pixel format” issue with a video created with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a strange problem with a video created with this command:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mkv -i in.mkv -ss 00:25:00 -t 180 -c copy out.mkv
```

The `out.mkv` is not playing on my player.

The `in.mkv` has this properties:

```
Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1200x720 [SAR 901:900 DAR 901:540], SAR 1:1 DAR 5:3, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 1k tbn, 48 tbc (default)
```

Stream #0:1(ita): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s (default)

The out.mkv has this properties:

```
Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264, none(tv, bt709, progressive), 1200x720, SAR 1:1 DAR 5:3, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 1k tbn, 2k tbc (default)
```

Stream #0:1(ita): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s (default)

And ffmpeg shows this warning:

```
Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264, none(tv, bt709, progressive), 1200x720): unspecified pixel format.
```

I have checked also keyframes and in the range 25-28 min they are present.

Why is this happening?

Comment: The original title to this question was “Strange with ffmpeg” which not only makes little sense, it doesn’t specify the issue. The error message itself indicates the issue: “…unspecified pixel format.” There is an [answer posted here already](https://superuser.com/a/1702239/167207) but please be sure to read the whole error message for details in the future. And please clearly state the issues in the title when you post a question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no pixel format defined in your output video.

You can define it by using the filter `-vf format=pix_fmts=yuv420p` or the option `-pix_fmt yuv420p`.